# "XML content cannot be parsed"

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, api-eveonline, google-sheets-formula

Google spreadsheet gives me an error stating "Imported XML content cannot be parsed" when I try to use the IMPORTXML function.

Cell contents:

`=IMPORTXML("http://api.eveonline.com/char/AccountBalance.xml.aspx?keyID=myKey&vCode=myVCode&characterID=myCharID","/eveapi/result/rowset/row@balance")`

where myKey, myVCode & myCharID are all valid (accessing the link via address bar with actual keys/IDs gives me a clean XML document).

The XPATH attempts to return the value for attribute "balance" in node "row".  eveapi is a root note.

The only information I've found on the web regarding this issue is that IMPORTXML cannot parse js, but there's no js to handle - output is literally a pure XML document.

Comment: I've got it working by using the Xpath `//@balance`.

No idea why that works but the query in the OP doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath is invalid. Using `/` you are doing an axis step. However, when you write `row@balance` you are not doing the required axis step to goi to the balance attribute. Hence, it must be

```
/eveapi/result/rowset/row/@balance
```